# issue in laravel 4 form data entry to DB

Tags: php, laravel-4

Hello i am trying to create a UI with fname and lname and i want it to be added to my mysql db table. 
following are my codes for reference.

```
**register1.blade.php**

@extends('master')

@section('content')


<div class="row">
    <div class="span4 offset1">
        <div class="well">
            <legend>Please Register Here</legend> <br/>
            {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'register1')) }}
            @if($errors->any())
            <div class="alert alert-error">
                            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
                {{ implode('', $errors->all('<li class="error">:message</li>')) }}
            </div>
            @endif
            First Name:{{ Form::text('fname', '', array('placeholder' => 'First Name')) }}<br>
            Last Name:{{ Form::text('lname', '',array('placeholder' => 'Last Name')) }}<br>
            {{ Form::submit('Submit', array('class' => 'btn btn-success')) }}
<!--            {{ HTML::link('register', 'Sign Up', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}-->
            {{ Form::close() }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@stop

**HomeController.php**

        public function getRegister1()
        {
            return View::make('home.register1');
        }
        public function postRegister1()
    {
        $input = Input::all();

        $rules = array('fname' => 'required', 'lname' => 'required');

        $v = Validator::make($input, $rules);

        if($v->fails())
        {

            return Redirect::to('register1')->withErrors($v);

        } else { 

            $credentials = array('fname' => $input['fname'], 'lname' => $input['lname']);

            if(Auth::attempt($credentials))
            {

                return Redirect::to('admin');

            } else {

                return Redirect::to('register1');
            }
        }
    }
**in models-> register.php**
<?php
use Illuminate\Auth\RegisterInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class register extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'register1';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password');

    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFirstName()
    {
        return $this->fname;
    }

    /**
     * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLastName()
    {
        return $this->lname;
    }
**routes.php**

Route::get('register1','HomeController@getRegister1');
Route::post('register1','HomeController@postRegister1');
```

when i execute registration it gives me text boxes and submit. onclick of submit i have the following error

```
**illuminate \ Database \ QueryException**

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'fname' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `fname` = sonu and `lname` = k limit 1) 

please help me out with this issue.
```

Comment: please post your table

Comment: Auth uses the users table, then probably the fname column does not exist

Comment: how to make Auth use register1 table because my feilds fname, lname is present in register1 table and i want the records to be inserted in the same register1 table

Answer (score 1):

It's throwing error because there is no **fname** column in **users** table. You should check your database structure, and make sure **fname** column exist.

Comment: fname column is in register table and i want it be saved in the same table. could you please let me know where and which code i should write to get it.

Comment: Can you show full exception stack of your error in your question?

Comment: could you please send me the code for inserting it into register1 table??

Comment: where should we write the insert query in laravel 4?

Comment: this is my exception stack  open: C:\wamp\www\EMS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php

    }
    // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    catch (\Exception $e)
    {
    throw new QueryException($query, $bindings, $e);
    }

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a `register` table with all the necessary columns, you would need to tell your app to use that table for authentication. So in `app/config/auth.php', depending on which driver you're using,  you'll need entries like the following:

```
'model' => 'register',
```

if you're using the 'eloquent' driver, or

```
'table' => 'register1'
```

if you're using the database driver.

Also, for what little it's worth, conventionally the class names for models are CamelCase and the table names are lowercase and plural. So, in your case, `class Register ....` and `protected $table = registers;`.

If the above doesn't get you up and running, maybe try looking through this tutorial: http://laravelbook.com/laravel-user-authentication/.